# What can I do to get a normal Python REPL from JetBrains

Tags: python, pycharm, read-eval-print-loop

I'm trying to write a program to do a simplification of a classic drinking song, and the Python interpreter is behaving really strangely.

My code reads:

```
def lines():
    bottles = 99
    while bottles > 0:
        yield str(bottles) + ' bottles of pop on the wall!'
        yield str(bottles) + ' bottles of pop!'
        yield 'Take one down and pass it around!'
        bottles -= 1
        yield str(bottles) + ' bottles of pop on the wall!'
        yield ''

def sing():
    for line in lines():
        print(line)
```

This runs as intended from the Linux command line; it may print "1 bottles of pop" but it does what I want for now.

However, from the "Python Console" in JetBrains, I am getting, under a couple of permutations:

```
>>> ninetynine.sing()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\chris\PycharmProjects\untitled\ninetynine.py", line 10, in sing
    for line in lines():
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

I tried to call it slightly differently, and got:

```
>>> for line in ninetynine.lines():
...    print(line)

99 bottles of pop on the wall!
99 bottles of pop!
Take one down and pass it around!
98 bottles of pop on the wall!
>>>
```

What I have not yet managed is to get it to act like a generator that runs over a loop.

What can, or should, I be doing to get proper REPL behavior from PyCharm?

**--UPDATE--**

There's some stupid caching going on.

I re-keyed the .py file, but entered the last yield statemest as,

```
        yield str(bottles + ' bottles of pop on the wall!')
```

This gave the obvious error, so I changed the source file and saved:

```
        yield str(bottles) + ' bottles of pop on the wall!
```

It reported the exact same error after I re-imported `bottles` from the REPL, only the line it pointed a finger at was my correct bottles.py line, which now correctly placed the `)` immediately after `bottles`.

So there is some kind of dirty caching going on; I think the source is failing to be recompiled or something like that.

Is there an option of a "make clean" or, better, a setting that will recompile if the source file is newer than the compiled form, or simply not save bytecode?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you are running your program. Where and how are you importing the file 'ninetynine'?

Comment: @PatrickConwell I saved the file in PyCharm, and then (off-camera) ran `import ninetynine` from a PyCharm REPL, rerunning it after I saved the file.

Comment: This is, incidentally, the only file on this computer that I've ever given a rough (or otherwise) implentation of "99 bottles of pop."

Comment: I just replied with an answer as well. It's working fine for me without modifying your code at all. What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Are you importing the file while in the console?

ninetynine.py:

```
def lines():
    bottles = 99
    while bottles > 0:
        yield str(bottles) + ' bottles of pop on the wall!'
        yield str(bottles) + ' bottles of pop!'
        yield 'Take one down and pass it around!'
        bottles -= 1
        yield str(bottles) + ' bottles of pop on the wall!'
        yield ''


def sing():
    for line in lines():
        print(line)
```

pycharm -> tools -> python console...

```
>>> import ninetynine

>>> ninetynine.sing()

99 bottles of pop on the wall!
99 bottles of pop!
Take one down and pass it around!
98 bottles of pop on the wall!

98 bottles of pop on the wall!
98 bottles of pop!
Take one down and pass it around!
97 bottles of pop on the wall!

...

1 bottles of pop on the wall!
1 bottles of pop!
Take one down and pass it around!
0 bottles of pop on the wall!
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: Let me try and make sure I’m accessing the console the same way you are...

Comment: What, if anything, can be done to force recompilation and any recaching of e.g. ninetynine.py?

Comment: The way you are writing your program, you are basically using it as a module. You will have to import any modules (including built-in modules) if you want to use them in your program. So, if you wanted to use this program in another program, you would need to add `import nintetynine` at the top of the file.

Python is not 'compiled', so you just need to import your module each time you use your program.

Comment: CPython *is* compiled in the sense of being run from bytecode (although not run from machine code); there is a chance of a .pyc file failing to be updated, and I believe this is happening.